# Draw a rectangle with DX11

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

I need to draw a simple rectangle (not a filled box) with directx 11.

I have found this code:

```
    const float x = 0.1;
    const float y = 0.1;
    const float height = 0.9;
    const float width = 0.9;
    
   VERTEX OurVertices[] =
    {
        { x, y, 0, col },
        { x + width, y, 0, col },
        { x, y + height, 0, col },
        { x + width, y, 0, col },
        { x + width, y + height, 0 , col },
        { x, y + height, 0, col }
    };

    static const XMVECTORF32 col = { 1.f, 2.f, 3.f, 4.f };

    // this is the function used to render a single frame
    void RenderFrameTest(void)
    {
        // float color[4] = { 0.0f, 0.2f, 0.4f, 1.0f };
        float color[4] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
    
        // clear the back buffer to a deep blue
        devcon->ClearRenderTargetView(backbuffer, color);
    
        // select which vertex buffer to display
        UINT stride = sizeof(VERTEX);
        UINT offset = 0;
    
         devcon->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &pVBuffer, &stride, &offset);
        // select which primtive type we are using
      //   draw the vertex buffer to the back buffer
        devcon->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLESTRIP);
        devcon->Draw(sizeof(OurVertices) / sizeof(VERTEX), 0);
      
        swapchain->Present(0, 0);
    
    }
    
    

   
    void DrawRectangle(float x, float y, float width, float height, XMVECTORF32 col)
    {
        D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bd;
        ZeroMemory(&bd, sizeof(bd));
        bd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
        bd.ByteWidth = sizeof(OurVertices);
        bd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
        bd.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
        HRESULT val = dev->CreateBuffer(&bd, NULL, &pVBuffer);                   // create the buffer
        D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE ms;
        val = devcon->Map(pVBuffer, NULL, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, NULL, &ms);   // map the buffer
        memcpy(ms.pData, OurVertices, sizeof(OurVertices));                      // copy the data
        devcon->Unmap(pVBuffer, NULL);
    }
```

but the result is not what I expected:

[image]

I suspect the problem is OurVertices array and "D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLESTRIP" but I don't have have experience with DirectX in general.

Can you help me please ?

Comment: You may want to take a look at [this tutorial](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Simple-rendering).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 6 vertices defined for a rectangle, which means you want to use TriangleList topology and not TriangleStrip topology.

Comment: thank you, however if change to "D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST" don't draw nothing.

Comment: That will have to do with vertex winding order. The default for DX11 is Clockwise for front face. Your vertices are forming triangles CounterClockwise. Try changing the order of vertices or rasterizer state (in order to set FrontCounterClockwise to TRUE)

Comment: You have right !! I followed your suggest and now draw a filled box. If I change to "D3D11_FILL_WIREFRAME" show 3 sides good but the 4° side is diagonal. My inpression is that I need to use "DrawIndexed" and not "Draw". What you think ?

Comment: Actually, DrawIndexed is used in order to avoid redundancy in vertices, so it does nothing to do with how those vertices are rendered. I think what you have to do is to draw some thin 4 rectangles or just 4 line segments.

Comment: Thank you now work !! last question there is a way to set the rectangle coordinate in pixel  ?

Comment: Yes there is. It is called a projection matrix. Usually applied to all vertices in vertex shader. I'm certain that any DirectX11 tutorial will let you know about this. By the way, the idea is simple. First, set coordinates of vertices in pixel. And then you just convert these coordinates into NDC(normalized device coordinates). If you know about NDC, this is not a hard thing to do, you could also do this even without a projection matrix.